# Oracle declaring and Using Dates

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I have been using SQL Server for about 7 years now, just changed jobs and a lot of our production stuff is in Oracle SQL Developer. Day 1, not enjoying Oracle but hoping for the best.

I am trying to do what I would think would be extremely simply and easy but all the methods i find only do not work. I run the below and get an Error.

> Bind Variable "Startdt" is NOT DECLARED anonymous block completed

I have tried declaring it several different ways, including how it Enddt is. DealerNbr works fine as is. The query itself i pulled from an SSRS report, but I have to declare the variables so i can test/add columns to it. the SSRS works fine.

```
DECLARE 
  DealerNbr NUMBER;
  Startdt DATE;
  Enddt DATE;
BEGIN
  DealerNbr := 18913;
  Startdt   := TO_DATE ('2012-01-01','mm,dd,yyyy');
  Enddt     := '2012-12-31';
END;

select prq_payee_nbr ,
prq_status_cd 
from payable_requisitions 
where prq_payee_nbr = :DealerNbr
and prq_status_cd <> 'V' 
and prq_dt between :Startdt and :Enddt
order by prq_dt
```

Essential I am just trying to do the most basic thing. In SQL Server it would be:

```
Declare @DealerNbr Int
,@Startdt date
,@EndDt date

Set @DealerNbr = '18913'
Set @Startdt = '2012-01-01'
Set @Enddt = '2012-12-31'

Select * 
from payable_requistion
where prq_payee_nbr = @DealerNbr
and prq_dt between @Startdt and @EndDt
```

Comment: The variables you declare are local to the anonymous PL/SQL block so they go out of scope after the `END`.  You could put the SQL statement inside the anonymous block.  But then you'd need to do something with the output-- you'd have to open a `sys_refcursor` variable or select the data into a local collection (assuming there are multiple rows), etc.  You can leave the query as is an let SQL Developer prompt you for values for the bind variables each time it executes.  I believe SQL Developer supports substitution variables as well.

Comment: Although it might require `&` instead of `:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;
/

DECLARE
  DealerNbr NUMBER := 18913;
  Startdt   DATE   := DATE '2012-01-01';
  Enddt     DATE   := DATE '2012-12-31';
BEGIN
  OPEN :cur FOR
  select prq_payee_nbr ,
         prq_status_cd 
  from   payable_requisitions 
  where  prq_payee_nbr = DealerNbr
  and    prq_status_cd <> 'V' 
  and    prq_dt between Startdt and Enddt
  order by prq_dtl;
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```

Or

```
VARIABLE Startdt VARCHAR2;
VARIABLE Enddt VARCHAR2;
VARIABLE DealerNbr NUMBER;

BEGIN
  :DealerNbr := 18913;
  :Startdt   := '2012-01-01';
  :Enddt     := '2012-12-31';
END;
/

select prq_payee_nbr ,
       prq_status_cd 
from   payable_requisitions 
where  prq_payee_nbr = :DealerNbr
and    prq_status_cd <> 'V' 
and    prq_dt between TO_DATE( :Startdt, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
              and     TO_DATE( :Enddt,   'YYYY-MM-DD' )
order by prq_dtl;
```

Comment: Brilliant, it worked perfectly. I never would have guessed all that extra stuff. Thanks

Comment: @HolmesIV If this has answered your question then you can mark the answer as correct (and I've updated the answer to make it a bit simpler and to give a second method).